# Dynamically create button on button_Click event in iphone

Tags: iphone, button, dynamic, view

I am having 1 main View.

In that I am having 3 subView.

In 1st view , I am having Button.

Now on that button's click event I am throwing 1 query.

And according to the count of items of that fetch , i want to display products on button.

So basically I want to create buttons dynamically..

Can anybody help me?

Comment: how do you want those buttons to get displayed? and in which subview first ,second or third?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(IBAction) yourbuttonclickevent:(UIButton *)button{
    for(int i=0;i<count_of_items;i++)
    {
         UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
         [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(i*100,0,100,200)];//setframe as per your requirement 
         btn.tag=i;
         [yoursubview addSubview:btn];
    }
}
```